# javascript_setInterval in combination with mouseenter

Tags: javascript, setinterval, addeventlistener, mouseenter

Here I have a really simple animation:

If you move over the area (300 x 250px), four pics will move from left to right (one after another). The problem is, that the setInterval getting faster the more often I move over the area.

I think the problem is the setInterval in combination with the event mouseenter ...but I dont know how to solve the problem.

```js
wrapper.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
  i = 0;
  ziel = 75;
  numberBild = 1;
  currentMove = -75;

  interval = window.setInterval(function() {
    if (i < ziel && numberBild <= 4) {
      currentMove = currentMove + 1;
      console.log(i);
      console.log(document.getElementById('bild-move-' + numberBild));
      console.log(currentMove);
      document.getElementById('bild-move-' + numberBild).style.marginLeft = currentMove + "px";
      i++;

    } else {
      i = 0;
      numberBild = numberBild + 1;
    }
  }, 10);
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" style="width:300px;height:250px;border:1px solid #dcdddd; ">
  <a id="bild-move-1" href="<mpvc/>https://<mpck/>&mpro=" target="_blank" style="position: absolute; z-index: 4; margin-left: -75px;"><img src="bild_01-a.jpg" width="75" border="0"></a>
  <a id="bild-move-2" href="<mpvc/>https://<mpck/>&mpro=" target="_blank" style="position: absolute; z-index: 3; margin-left: -75px;"><img src="bild_01-a.jpg" width="75" border="0"></a>
  <a id="bild-move-3" href="<mpvc/>https://<mpck/>&mpro=" target="_blank" style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; margin-left: -75px;"><img src="bild_01-a.jpg" width="75" border="0"></a>
  <a id="bild-move-4" href="<mpvc/>https://<mpck/>&mpro=" target="_blank" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; margin-left: -75px;"><img src="bild_01-a.jpg" width="75" border="0"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Next time you ask a question, please familiarize with [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) before editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time your `mouseenter` event gets hit, you're resetting all your variables, but more importantly - your interval.

Define your variables outside of all the events, and make sure you only set your interval *if it hasn't already been set*. Additionally, your interval has no end. You should really consider stopping it once your animation is complete.

I've moved your animation to a function to neaten things up slightly, and cleared your interval once the animation is complete by using `clearInterval()`.

```js
//Initialize interval (and variables) outside of the interval
var interval = null;
var i = 0;
var ziel = 75;
var numberBild = 1;
var currentMove = -75;
var numberOfBilds = 4;

function resetVars() {
  i = 0;
  ziel = 75;
  numberBild = 1;
  currentMove = -75;
  for (var j = 1; j <= numberOfBilds; j++) {
    document.getElementById('bild-move-' + j).style.marginLeft = 0;
  }
}

//Function to start the animation
function startAnimation() {

  //Only set the interval if it hasn't already been set
  if (interval == null) {

    resetVars();

    interval = setInterval(function() {
      if (i < ziel && numberBild <= 4) {
        currentMove = currentMove + 1;
        document.getElementById('bild-move-' + numberBild).style.marginLeft = currentMove + "px";
        i++;
      } else {

        //If there are still Bilds left to be animated, increment and continue
        if (numberBild <= numberOfBilds) {
          i = 0;
          numberBild = numberBild + 1;
        } else { //otherwise, animation is complete, clear the interval
          clearInterval(interval);
          interval = null;
        }

      }
    }, 10);
  }
}

wrapper.addEventListener("mouseenter", startAnimation);
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" style="width:300px;height:250px;border:1px solid #dcdddd; ">
  <a id="bild-move-1" href="<mpvc/>https://<mpck/>&mpro=" target="_blank" style="position: absolute; z-index: 4; margin-left: -75px;"><img src="bild_01-a.jpg" width="75" border="0"></a>
  <a id="bild-move-2" href="<mpvc/>https://<mpck/>&mpro=" target="_blank" style="position: absolute; z-index: 3; margin-left: -75px;"><img src="bild_01-a.jpg" width="75" border="0"></a>
  <a id="bild-move-3" href="<mpvc/>https://<mpck/>&mpro=" target="_blank" style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; margin-left: -75px;"><img src="bild_01-a.jpg" width="75" border="0"></a>
  <a id="bild-move-4" href="<mpvc/>https://<mpck/>&mpro=" target="_blank" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; margin-left: -75px;"><img src="bild_01-a.jpg" width="75" border="0"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your result is nearly perfect. But the problem is, that the he animation should be repeated as soon as the movement is finished and a new mouseenter event was triggered

Comment: Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309237/dealing-with-questions-that-are-edited-after-my-answer-has-been-accepted), or [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299405/should-a-question-edit-be-rolled-back-if-it-appears-to-be-a-follow-up-to-an-answ), or [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253762/link-for-poor-or-ever-growing-questions-to-better-explain-why-people-stop-answer) - I answered your question, you accepted it, and then you changed your question... I've edited my answer, but moving forward, please realize this is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem Santi pointed out, try this:

```
var interval;//global scope
wrapper.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
  var i = 0,
  ziel = 75,
  numberBild = 1,
  currentMove = -75;

  interval = interval || window.setInterval(function() { //just set if it doesnt exist already
  if (i < ziel && numberBild <= 4) {
    currentMove = currentMove + 1;
    console.log(i,document.getElementById('bild-move-' + numberBild),currentMove);
    document.getElementById('bild-move-' + numberBild).style.marginLeft = currentMove + "px";
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
    numberBild = numberBild + 1;
  }
 }, 10);
 });
```

On mouseout, you may want to reset the interval:

```
 wrapper.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
   window.clearInterval(interval);
   interval=null;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code...

Replace script with below code and try

i just reset(clear) interval on mouse out event

```
<script>
var interval = 1;
wrapper.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
    i = 0;
    ziel = 75;
    numberBild = 1;
    currentMove = -75;

    interval = window.setInterval(function() {
        if (i < ziel && numberBild <=4) {
            currentMove = currentMove + 1;
            //console.log (i);
            //console.log (document.getElementById('bild-move-'+ numberBild));
            //console.log (currentMove);
            document.getElementById('bild-move-'+ numberBild).style.marginLeft = currentMove + "px";
            i++;

        } else {
            i = 0;
            numberBild = numberBild + 1;
        }
    }, 10);

});

 wrapper.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
    clearInterval(interval);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot an important information:
**A further problem is, that the he animation should be repeated as soon as the movement is finished and a new mouseenter event was triggered**

I tried it by myself with **your** code examples. It works... but maybe it isn't that eloquent

```
<script>
//Initialize interval (and variables) outside of the interval
var interval = null;
var indexA = 0;
var ziel = 75;
var numberofThePic = 1;
var currentMove = -75;

//Function to start the animation
function startAnimation() {

    //Only set the interval if it hasn't already been set
    if (interval == null) {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            if (numberofThePic <=4) {
                if (indexA < ziel){
                    currentMove = currentMove + 1;
                    document.getElementById('bild-move-'+ numberofThePic).style.marginLeft = currentMove + "px";
                    indexA++;
                } else {
                    indexA = 0;
                    numberofThePic = numberofThePic + 1;
                }
            } else {
             //otherwise, animation is complete, clear the interval
                setTimeout(function(){ 
                    for (var indexB = 4; indexB >= 1; indexB--) {
                        document.getElementById('bild-move-'+ indexB).style.marginLeft = -75 + "px";
                    } 
                    indexA = 0;
                    numberofThePic = 1;
                    currentMove = -75;
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    interval = null;
                }, 2000);                    
            }

        }, 10);
    }
}

wrapper.addEventListener("mouseenter", startAnimation);
</script>
```